# Is there a way to show the sheet has been updated remotely via the API?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

When Smartsheet is updated by another used using the GUI, another user viewing the sheet will get visual notification that the sheet has been updated - requiring a save and/or refresh.

Is there a way to trigger this functionality from the API.
I'm using the  <kbd>Python SDK 2.0</kbd> and  <kbd>Python 3.5</kbd>

Thanks.

Craig

Answer (score 0):

The sheet *version* is incremented every time the sheet changes. You can use [get_sheet_version(sheet_id)](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-python-sdk/smartsheet.html#smartsheet.sheets.Sheets.get_sheet_version) to get a baseline version, then check again to see if it has changed. This is a very lightweight call.

Alternatively, the native Smartsheet REST API supports [Webhooks](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#intro-to-webhooks) to provide a callback when a sheet is changed. But this requires that you have a web server running and isn't wrapped by the Python SDK.

Comment: My question was misunderstood. When I update the sheet via the API, the GUI indicator does not change. Should it and if so, why might it not be updated by my API code?

Answer (score 0):

The GUI indicator will eventually alert you to a change regardless of where the update came from. Sometimes, that change can be a little delayed in the UI itself though.

Comment: I'll watch for it next time. Until then, can you define "a little delayed"? I thought I had waited several minutes but maybe I was too eager.