# Apscheduler issues with uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, apscheduler

I have a Python Flask App with Apscheduler that checks if there is a change in an online spreadsheet (Smartsheet). I am caching contents of the spreadsheet in a dictionary (in memory).

Everything works fine with the built-in Flask development web server, as well with uwsgi command.

However, when I serve the application with nginx + uwsgi, it seems that the scheduler does not work.

My question is, will uwsgi spawn multiple copies of the Flask app?

How do I use uwsgi mule to trigger a function in the main Flask app?

Any pointers is much appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Hantzley

Comment: There may be some easier ways to check when the sheet has been updated with the Smartsheet API. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538435/is-there-a-way-to-show-the-sheet-has-been-updated-remotely-via-the-api).